Topological phase transitions in BKT-like system: relation to directed percolation
I am studying a non-equilibrium system that transitions between an unbound vortex state to a bound vortex state, that 'looks' like properties of BKT system.
I am interested in the self-organising processing from the disordered to the quasi-ordered state. We see the emergence of power-law clusters in our spatial data.
Is this type of topological phase transition likely to be a form of directed percolation?
